# "Reply-to" value not working in Contact Form 7 (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, forms, email, plugins, contact-form-7

On my Wordpress website I use Contact Form 7 plugin. As you may know, in plugin configuration there's a field called "Additional headers" where "Reply-To: [your-email]" value is put by default. However, It simply doesn't work - when someone sends me a message via the form, I'm not able to reply to his email address but mine instead, which makes no sense. Long story short, I can only reply to myself.

It's not a conflict with any other plugin nor theme and my mail provider says they don't block "Reply-to" function. I tried reaching out to CF7 author but no luck. I feel like I've tried everything - does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue once for good?

My settings in CF7:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pZzF.jpg
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CToIU.jpg

Answer (score -2):

Make the **from** and **to** field different addresses. For example

```
To: kontakt@domain.pl 
From: [Kontakt] noreply@domain.pl
```

In some cases it works.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly it doesn't work. Got any other ideas?

Answer (score -3):

As suggested, putting different emails in the To and From fields worked for me (both with the site domain). After doing that, the Reply-To: [your-email] was applied to the "To" field in my email when I hit reply.